# Asymptotic expansion of $\int_0^\infty \frac{ e^{-i\mu(e^x-1)} - e^{-ix}}{x} dx$ as $\mu \to 0^+$?

Tags: integration, asymptotics

What is the asymptotic expansion of
$$I(\mu) = \int_0^\infty \frac{ e^{-i\mu(e^x-1)} - e^{-ix}}{x} dx,$$
as $\mu \to 0^+$? Note that the integrand is non-singular at $x=0$, so that $I(\mu)$ is well-defined.

Remark: If the exponent $e^x-1$ is replaced to a polynomial $P(x)= a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1x$ that satisfies $P(0)=0$, then the asymptotic expansion of
\begin{align*}
I_P(\mu) &= \int_0^\infty \frac{ e^{-i\mu P(x)} - e^{-ix}}{x} dx \\
&= -\log(\mu^{1/n}) + O(1)
\end{align*}
can be obtained with explicit representation for $O(1)$ term, modulo order-of-limit issue.

First, we manipulate by adding and subtracting $e^{-ix\mu^{1/n}}$:
$$I_P(\mu) = \int_0^\infty \left[ \frac{ e^{-i\mu P(x)} - e^{-ix\mu^{1/n}}}{x} - \frac{e^{-ix} -e^{-ix\mu^{1/n}}}{x}  \right] dx,$$
and evaluate the second integral explicitly:
$$I_P(\mu) = \int_0^\infty\frac{ e^{-i\mu P(x)} - e^{-ix\mu^{1/n}}}{x} dx - \log(\mu^{1/n}).$$
For the remaining integral, letting $x = \mu^{-1/n} t$ gives
$$I_P(\mu) = \int_0^\infty \frac{ e^{-i\mu P(\mu^{-1/n}\:t)} - e^{-it} }{t} dt - \log(\mu^{1/n}).$$
Since we have the limit $\mu P(\mu^{-1/n}\:t) \to a_nt^n$ as $\mu\to 0^+$, we expect $\mu \to 0^+$  limit of the integral to be
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ia_nt^n} -e^{-it}}{t} dt,$$
which is finite. (This manipulation is valid modulo order-of-limit issue.) This is the expected $O(1)$ term of $I_P(\mu)$.